# Flushing short lines left and long lines right in lines environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context, justification

How can I get short lines flushed left and longer lines (which have to be broken in two or more) justified and flushed right in lines environment by using only environment setup options in ConTeXt?

Here is an example:

```
\mainlanguage[pl]
\setupalign[nothyphenated]
\starttext
\startlines[align=flushright]
  Arch. Fil. MLAM – Archiwum Filomatów w Muzeum Literatury im. Adama Mickiewicza w Warszawie
  Arch. Montalembert – Archives Montalembert, zamek La Roche en Brenil
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

which results in [image: this output] The first line "Arch. Fil. MLAM…" has to be broken in two, the resulting upper line should be justified but is flushed right and the lower line is flushed right as well, which is what I want. The second line "Arch. Montalembert…" is not long enough to be broken and in that case I would like to have it flushed left. How could that be obtained without setting alignment on each line?

What I would like it to look like can be obtained with

```
\mainlanguage[pl]
\setupalign[nothyphenated]
\starttext
\startlines[align=flushright]
  \inframed[width=\textwidth, align=no, frame=off]{Arch. \hfill Fil. \hfill  MLAM \hfill – \hfill Archiwum \hfill Filomatów \hfill w \hfill  Muzeum \hfill Literatury \hfill im. \hfill Adama}
  \rightaligned{Mickiewicza w Warszawie}
  \leftaligned{Arch. Montalembert – Archives Montalembert, zamek La Roche en Brenil}
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

and looks like this [image]

Comment: Hi, John. This is not LaTeX, this is ConTeXt question and the example is in the first code sample.

Comment: What you are trying to do looks pretty much line like traditional verse breaking (at least in French). I would rather try without `flushright` option. Btw, since you are explaining abbrevs, wouldn't a description environment fit more your needs ?

Comment: As a work around, you can use gmverse in lualatex. Maybe some ConTeXt guru could port its internal to ConTeXt. Its author told me it was playing with catcodes, so looks like TeX internals code.

Comment: In principle, `align=end` is supposed to achieve this result, but in my tests, it does not work. So, I suggest that you write the the context mailing list.

Comment: If this were LaTeX, I would use `\parindent=\fill`, but don't know and can't test with ConTeXt.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That would flush all unbroken lines right.  OP only wants to flush “short” lines right, whatever threshold “short” means.

Comment: @Aditya I guess `align=end` simply sets `\parfillskip=0pt` to make the last line stretch all the way to the right boundary.

Comment: Actually it stretches both the first and second line. If there was a way to leave the first line as it is with align=end and flush the second right!

Comment: Sorry, \hangindent=\fill

Comment: @HenriMenke: No, it has a `\leftparfillskip=\hfill` (or something similar, typing based on my memory) and then there is some lua code that checks for `\leftparfillskip` and applies it when the paragraph is being built. My guess is that the lua code is not working as intended.